# Wordpress, querying pages by category and displaying meta info

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have a wordpress blog that has a theme with some custom code to access posts by category. I've not used wordpress until now, and would like to make this code work for pages instead of posts. So far I've tried a few basic queries from codex.wordpress.org without much success.

Can anyone assist with this please?

```
<?php $some_array_of_pages = new WP_Query( array( 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,    'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'category_name' => 'category'  ) ); ?>
  <?php while ($some_array_of_pages->have_posts()) : ?>    
  <?php $properties->the_post(); ?>
<?php $meta1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_name', true ); ?>
<?php $meta2 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_name', true ); ?>
<?php if ($meta1 && $meta2): ?>
//do something here                              
<?php endif; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'post_type' to your query:

```
<?php $some_array_of_pages = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'=>'page'  ) ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Full example from OP:

```
<?php $some_array_of_pages = new WP_Query( array( 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,    'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'category_name' => 'category', 'post_type' => 'page'  ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Hi There, thanks for answering this for me. I tried your answer and it's not returning any results. I'm assuming this is because there are no pages in that category?

Comment: That's very possible. If you want, try the first query. It will return all pages, regardless of any other factors.